# PowerShell scriptblock scope weirdness

Tags: powershell, scope

I am using `Invoke-Command` on the local (not remote) computer to run a scriptblock that includes a function.  Some of the variables defined at the "root" of the scriptblock are available in the function, and some require me to scope them as `Global:`.

So in quasi-code, this fails:

```
{
function test() {
   if (test-path $filepath.trim('t')) {
      $taskFolder.gettasks(1) |out-file '$env:temp\tasks.txt'
   }
}

$filepath = '$env:temp\test.txt'
$TaskService    = new-object -ComObject('Schedule.Service')
$TaskService.connect()
$TaskFolder = $TaskService.GetFolder('\')
test
}
```

with a "You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression." (i.e. `$filepath -eq $null`).

However, this works:

```
{
function test() {
   if (test-path $Global:filepath.trim('t')) {
      $taskFolder.gettasks(1) |out-file '$env:temp\tasks.txt'
   }
}

$Global:filepath = '$env:temp\test.txt'
$TaskService    = new-object -ComObject('Schedule.Service')
$TaskService.connect()
$TaskFolder = $TaskService.GetFolder('\')
test
}
```

even though `$TaskFolder` is not Global.

I can't seem to replicate the problem with short, simple code like this here, but the effect of *ONLY* globally scoping a couple variables makes all the difference.

I initially noticed the issue when I was attempting to use the variables with `Script:` scope and that was failing.  I assumed that was because this was a script block and not an actual script.  Changing to `Global:` resolved the problem and then I noticed the non-scoped `$taskfolder` variable.

**I am not asking about scheduled tasks!**  I only included it in the example because that is the variable that is working fine without being assigned a global scope.

Obviously, I'm not understanding something about scoping, invoking, or maybe the Schedule Service.

Can someone enlighten me?

Comment: Where are you ever invoking `test`?  It's never used in your code.  Your syntax is also terrible

Comment: Whoops!  My quasi-code was incomplete and yes, the syntax is poor.  I'm just passing on the concept.

Comment: I'd save yourself the headache and just utilize schtasks.exe rather than messing with the com object.

Comment: Or, if you can, [use the ScheduledTasks PowerShell module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/scheduledtasks/?view=win10-ps).

Comment: This works for me returning `1`: `Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { $x = 0; function y { $x.ToString().Trim('2'); }; $x = 12; y }`.  What version of PowerShell are you on?

Comment: Unless you provide the code, which allows to replicate your problem, it is not possible to answer, what is wrong with your code, because we are not seeing it.

Comment: I'm not having a problem with scheduled tasks!  While I am stuck with PoSh v2, so the module isn't going to work, the com object works just fine for me.  The issue is about scope.  Some variables' scope carry into child functions as they are supposed to, and others do not.  If I convert this scriptblock to a script, it runs without the need for the `global` designations which tells me something is funny about scope for scriptblocks.